# Issue with file upload clickable zone in Firefox with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a template based on Bootstrap 3 and there is a weird display issue with Firefox for file input elements: basically the click area covers a huge part of the page, which means that anything around them cannot be clicked without triggering a file upload.

Here is what I mean by large area (with Firebug, based on the `<input type="file">` element):
[image]

While with Chrome it's fine:
[image]

And with IE it's also fine.

Here is the link to the theme page where you see the issue (only happening to the first type of "advanced file input", where the input element itself is displayed): http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic_admin/components_form_tools.html

And here is the code for the file display:

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="input-group input-large">
        <div class="form-control uneditable-input span3" data-trigger="fileinput">
            <i class="fa fa-file fileinput-exists"></i>&nbsp;
            <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-addon btn default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file" name="documents-0">
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can force the input element click zone to stay within its limits on Firefox?

Thanks in advance!